# Spring: Custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver for ExceptionHandler Methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written an implementation of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and configured it like this:

`<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean class="com.mypackage.MyResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>`

This works as I expect for methods marked with `@RequestMapping`. When I use my custom argument as a parameter to a `@RequestMapping` method, MyResolver is invoked, and I get my expected argument value.

However, it does not work for methods marked with `@ExceptionHandler`, and if I try to use my custom argument as a parameter, the `@ExceptionHandler` method is not invoked at all.

Is it possible to apply a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to `@ExceptionHandler` methods?

Comment: When use @ExceptionHandler your method can have only few parameters like HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HttpSession, Exception(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

Why do you need a custom parameter?

Shouldn't be enough this?

 **@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
 public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception { }**

Comment: Not through XML. You'll need to register your own `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` with the appropriate argument resolvers.